# Typing as Class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have an interface or abstract class in TypeScript, and I have a whole bunch of classes that either implement/extend the interface/class, and I want to make an array out of all the subclasses' constructors, but I want the array typed as the interface/superclass. Is this possible?

So if I have:

```
export interface Section {
    somePropName: string;
}
```

or:

```
export class AbstractSection {
    somePropName: string;
}
```

And then I have:

```
arrayOfClasses: any[] = [
    SectionSubclass1,
    SectionSubclass2,
    SectionSubclass3,
    SectionSubclass4,
    SectionSubclass5,
];
```

Can I type `arrayOfClasses` to anything other than `any[]`? I'd like to get as specific as possible. I know in ActionScript you could at least do `Vector.<Class>`, and in Haxe you could do `Array<Class>`, but in TypeScript you can't even type as `Class`, AFAIK.

Comment: `arrayOfClasses: AbstractSection[] = [...];` or `arrayOfClasses: Section[] = [...];`.

Comment: Wouldn't those be expecting instances, and not constructors?

Comment: Do you want to put the class itself in the array or its instances? If you want to store the classes themselves, you can `arrayOfClasses: Array<typeof AbstractSection> = [...];`.

Comment: Ah, yes! That sounds like what I want!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to store classes:

```
arrayOfClasses: Array<typeof AbstractSection> = [...];
```

If you want to store instances of the classes or implementation of interfaces:

```
arrayOfClasses: AbstractSection[] = [...];
```

Comment: Will try this tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I should mention this doesn't work on an interface, only on a class. If you try it on an interface, you get: "'Section' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

Comment: That is correct, because classes are real JavaScript objects, but interfaces are meta definitions that only exists in TypeScript.